# glut, glew dll : Binary was not built with debug information

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, glut, glew

This is the output I am getting and

`'abc.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\system\glut32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'`

`'abc.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glew32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.`

`The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1710) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`
`The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x16a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`
`The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1770) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`
`The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1708) has exited with code 1 (0x1).`
`The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1778) has exited with code 1 (0x1).`
`The program '[600] abc.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).`
Any idea as to how I can fix this ?

I have tried the same on VS2008 VS2010. with almost the very same result. How can I force a binary to be built ? I can't find any correct project options.
Thank you very much.

-Egon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. You either need dll files already built with debug information, or link to external debug information (I doubt those exist ready for glu32 and glew32). What you're having is not an error, and should not be dealt as such.
If you have instead the source files for glut and glew, those warnings will cease to exist.

Comment: how can I avoid the code exit then? the program is compiling but not running ....

Comment: I am trying to tell you that the problem is not in the compiling. I have a similar setup that has glut and glew, and visual studio does give me the same message about the debug. The problem is in the code, which you should post a separate question for.